# Numerical solution of a BVP with a boundary value at infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Lets say we want to solve $y''=x y$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y(\infty)=0$

I know that this is the airy equation but how would one solve such an equation numerically?